# C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Game Projects\SFML projects\Test\Render.cpp|15|error: 'class std::vector<Character>' has no member named 'getSprite'|

Tags: c++, sfml

I keep getting this error

```
C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Game Projects\SFML projects\Test\Render.cpp|21|error: 'class std::vector<Character>' has no member named 'getSprite'|
```

I'm trying to accept a `vector` of `pointers` containing type `Character` class. The correct header file is included, so that's not the issue. I've been trying to figure this out for about the past hour or so but i'm totally lost. I thought I had done it correctly. Help greatly appreciated!

```
void Render::draw(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::vector<Character>* foreground, std::vector<Character>* background, std::vector<Character>* scenery)
{

window->clear();
for(int a = 0; a<scenery->size(); a++ )
{

    window->draw(scenery[a].getSprite());

}
for(int b = 0; b<background->size(); b++ )
{

    window->draw(background[b].getSprite());

}
for(int c = 0; c<foreground->size(); c++ )
{

    window->draw(foreground[c].getSprite());

}

window->display();

}
```

Comment: You are passing pointers to vectors. Think of what happens when you apply `operator[]` to a pointer.

Comment: It tries to access or create an `array` of `pointers`?

Comment: It treats it as an array of vectors. Better pass by reference.

Comment: Could you give me a code example? I'm slightly confused

Comment: `std::vector<something>* yourvector` becomes `std::vector<something>& yourvector`. You must change arguments. You must also change function in order to use instances and not pointers i.e. `foreground->size()` became `foregroung.size()`.

Comment: Ok it clicked in my head what you were saying! and i fixed it. Thanks a lot @juanchopanza

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
void Render::draw(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::vector<Character>* foreground, std::vector<Character>* background, std::vector<Character>* scenery)
{

window->clear();
for(int a = 0; a<scenery->size(); a++ )
{

    window->draw((*scenery)[a].getSprite());

}
for(int b = 0; b<background->size(); b++ )
{

    window->draw((*background)[b].getSprite());

}
for(int c = 0; c<foreground->size(); c++ )
{

    window->draw((*foreground)[c].getSprite());

}

window->display();

}
```